# Parameter values as a function of another vector. deSolve

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration, ode, desolve

I'm looking to set up a population dynamics model where each parameter value corresponds to the temperature of that day. e.g.

Simple model

```
 library(deSolve)
set.seed(1)

pars <- c(alpha = 1, beta = 0.2, delta = 0.5, gamma = 0.2)



lv_model <- function(pars, times = seq(0, 50, by = 1)) {
  # initial state 
  state <- c(x = 1, y = 2)
  # derivative
  deriv <- function(t, state, pars) {
    with(as.list(c(state, pars)), {
      d_x <- alpha * x - beta * x * y
      d_y <- delta * beta * x * y - gamma * y
      return(list(c(x = d_x, y = d_y)))
    })
  }
  # solve
  ode(y = state, times = times, func = deriv, parms = pars)
}
lv_results <- lv_model(pars = pars, times = seq(0, 50, by = 1))
```

I now want to use a sequence of daily temperatures
`DailyTemperature<-floor(runif(50,0,40))`

and make the parameter values functions of temperatures

```
TraitTemperature<-seq(1,40,1)

#trait responses to temperature
alpha<- abs(rnorm(40,mean = 0.5,sd=1))
beta<- abs(rnorm(40,mean = 0.2,sd=0.5))
delta<-abs(rnorm(40,mean=1,sd=2))
gamma<- seq(0.025,1,0.025)
parameters<-as.data.frame(cbind(TraitTemperature,alpha,beta,delta,gamma))
```

So that for each time step iterated over, it looks at the daily temperature and then finds the corresponding temperature values in the parameter data frame.

Looking back through the archives i've seen `if/else` statements used when wanting to alter single parameters at particular time steps and the use of forcing functions but I don't think they apply here.

I hope this makes sense, I'm interesting in ideas on how to make it work. So far i've also attempted using a `for loop` to iterate through the daily temperature list and then the `match` function to identify values but this didn't tap into the daily time steps.

Comment: Not got much experience with `deSolve`, but I do do a lot of this type of  dynamic modeling using an iterative approach.  So another way to solve this may be to conver you DE into a format in which value of `y` at time `t` is a function of the state at time `t-1`.  Then iterate over the function in a loop.  If speed is an issue, best to do this iteration in Rcpp, because R can get a bit slow for this kind of thing.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then this is what we call **forcing**. You find more about this in the deSolve help page `?forcings` or for example the following page: https://tpetzoldt.github.io/deSolve-forcing/deSolve-forcing.html

Comment: There are several ways to to this. One idea is to create 4 signals for the parameters, depending on the temperature, but if the index of the signal (e.g. the temperature) corresponds exactly to the time vector, it can also be made with index access (see below). Another way could be be to use `approxTime1`  from package **simecol**, that is able to return a whole vector of parameter values at once. Finally, it can also be done with a back-call, where `parms` is a function that does arbitrary interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

Here a possible approach using `DailyTemperature` as forcing and then the `parameters` data frame as lookup table. It does not need `match` here as long as the temperatures are integers and the temperatures in the data frame correspond to the row index of the data frame.

I want to add that, in principle, discontinuous forcings make the model slow, because an ODE is a continuous by definition. Fortunately, as the solvers are quite robust, it should for practical applications:

```r
library(deSolve)
set.seed(1)

deriv <- function(t, state, pars) {

  pars <- parameters[DailyTemperature[floor(t + 1)], 2:5]
  #print(pars)
  
  with(as.list(c(state, pars)), {
    d_x <- alpha * x - beta * x * y
    d_y <- delta * beta * x * y - gamma * y
    list(c(x = d_x, y = d_y), alpha=alpha, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, delta=delta)
  })
}


state <- c(x = 1, y = 2)
times = seq(0, 50, by = 1)

# pars <- c(alpha = 1, beta = 0.2, delta = 0.5, gamma = 0.2)
parameters <- data.frame(
  TraitTemperature = seq(1,40,1),
  alpha = abs(rnorm(40,mean = 0.5,sd=1)),
  beta = abs(rnorm(40,mean = 0.2,sd=0.5)),
  delta = abs(rnorm(40,mean=1,sd=2)),
  gamma = seq(0.025,1,0.025)
)


DailyTemperature <- floor(runif(51, 0, 40)) # one more because start zero

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = deriv, parms = pars)
plot(out)
```

[image: Temperature dependend parameters]

### Parameters as a list

In the example above, the `pars` variable passed from `ode` is just overwritten with `pars` derived from the global variables `parameters` and `DailyTemperature`. This works, but one may also consider to pass both as a list to the `deriv` function.

```r
deriv <- function(t, state, p) {
  
  parameters <- p[[1]]
  DailyTemperature <- p[[2]]

  parms <- parameters[DailyTemperature[floor(t + 1)], 2:5]
  # ...
}
```

and then:

```r
out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = deriv,
  parms = list(parameters, DailyTemperature))
```

Comment: Amazing thank you! I'll be using temperature values at .1 intervals, so im guessing i'd use the ```match``` function on line 4 of your code?

``` pars <- parameters[match(DailyTemperature[floor(t + 1)], 2:5$TraitTemperature]) ```

Comment: You can also use interpolation with `approxfun` to get the parameter row for a given temperature or, even faster, a formula to calculate the index directly.

Comment: So i've had a look at understanding approxfun The issue im having is making it a function of time and DailyTemperature. e.g. 

```alphainput<- approxfun(alpha,rule = 2)```

 would iterate through the alpha vector but not necessarily with regard to DailyTemperature. I'm also not that great with indexing. Any thoughts? Really appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for indexing using the current reproducible code:

```
set.seed(1)
deriv <- function(t, state, pars) {
  pars<- parameters[match(parameters$TraitTemperature[parameters[2:5]],DailyTemperature),]
  #print(pars)
  
  with(as.list(c(state, pars)), {
    d_x <- alpha * x - beta * x * y
    d_y <- delta * beta * x * y - gamma * y
    list(c(x = d_x, y = d_y), alpha=alpha, beta=beta, gamma=gamma, delta=delta)
  })
}

state <- c(x = 1, y = 2)
times = seq(0, 50, by = 1)

# pars <- c(alpha = 1, beta = 0.2, delta = 0.5, gamma = 0.2)
parameters <- data.frame(
  TraitTemperature = seq(1,40,1),
  alpha = abs(rnorm(40,mean = 0.5,sd=1)),
  beta = abs(rnorm(40,mean = 0.2,sd=0.5)),
  delta = abs(rnorm(40,mean=1,sd=2)),
  gamma = seq(0.025,1,0.025)
)

DailyTemperature <- floor(runif(51, 0, 40)) # one more because start zero

out <- ode(y = state, times = times, func = deriv, parms = pars)
plot(out)
```

but if I increase the resolution of the values e.g.

```
# Parameter datasets 
parameters <- data.frame(
  TraitTemperature = seq(0.1,40,0.1),
  alpha = abs(rnorm(400,mean = 0.5,sd=1)),
  beta = abs(rnorm(400,mean = 0.2,sd=0.5)),
  delta = abs(rnorm(400,mean=1,sd=2)),
  gamma = seq(0.0025,1,0.0025)
)

# random daily temperature dataset 
DailyTemperature <- round(runif(51, 0, 40),1) # one more because start zero
```

Then I get NA's at certain time steps

Comment: Here it would be better to ask another question. I can nevertheless write a second answer to this question, but in order to avoid confusion to SO users who may read this later, I suggest you extract the specific question and then ask it again. We can then move Q+A to the new thread remove obsolete code from here.

Answer (score 0):

The OP extended her/his question, so it may be the preferred way to start a new thread, but in order to give quick feedback, I try give another answer.

Several methods exist for interpolation or indexing in 2D (time and temperature). My preferred way would be to create a 2D model and then tu use a 2D interpolation method. This works best if the parameters surface would be smooth and not just random as in the given example. However, to make it simple, one can also use rounding and table lookup. If values are not integers, exact comparison does often not work due to rounding effects and limited precision (IEEE number formats), so instead of match, one can use `which.min`:

```r
DailyTemperature <- round(runif(51, 0, 40), 1)

TraitTemperature <- seq(0, 40, by=0.1)
N <- length(TraitTemperature)

parameters <- data.frame(
  TraitTemperature = TraitTemperature,
  alpha = abs(rnorm(N, mean = 0.5, sd=1)),
  beta = abs(rnorm(N, mean = 0.2, sd=0.5)),
  delta = abs(rnorm(N, mean=1,sd=2)),
  gamma = seq(0.025, 1, length.out=N)
)


t <- 17
actualTemp <- DailyTemperature[floor(t+1)]
actualTemp
pars <- parameters[which.min(abs(actualTemp - parameters$TraitTemperature)), 1:5]

head(pars)
```